# Facing error with null execption in flutter login page, what to do?

Tags: flutter, dart

so, i have been building this app, and all the way it worked perfectly fine, but suddenly it is showing null execption error after i finished building the app, may be i updated the sdk, but it is not working properly anymore.
Here is a snippet of my code:
i have been looking around and did a lot of things but nothing is working, tried updating the sdk and downgrading to stable version, but nothing working please help.
can someone please specify what the error is and where it is coming from

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project/screens/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:project/screens/sign_up.dart';
import 'package:project/services/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:project/utils/appvalidator.dart';


class LoginView extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginView({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginView> createState() => _LoginViewState();
}


class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  var isLoader = false;
  var authService = AuthService();



  Future<void> _submitForm() async {

    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        isLoader = true;
      });


      var data = {
        "email": _emailController.text,
        "password": _passwordController.text,

      };


      await authService.login(data, context);

      setState(() {
        isLoader = false;
      });
    }
  }

  var appValidator = AppValidator();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF252634),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Form(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 80.0,

                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 250,
                    child: Text("Login Account",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 28, fontWeight:
                          FontWeight.bold),),
                  ),

                  SizedBox(
                    height: 16.0,

                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                      controller: _emailController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      decoration: _buildInputDecoration("Email", Icons.email),
                      validator: appValidator.validateEmail
                  ),

                  SizedBox(
                    height: 16.0,

                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                      controller: _passwordController,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      decoration: _buildInputDecoration(
                          "Password", Icons.lock),
                      validator: appValidator.validatePassword
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 16.0,

                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF15900)
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            isLoader? print("Loading") :_submitForm();
                          },

                          child: isLoader
                              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                              : Text( "Login",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),))),
                  SizedBox(
                      height: 30.0
                  ),
                  TextButton(onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpView()),
                    );
                  },
                      child: Text("Create New Account",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFFF15900),
                            fontSize: 20),)),


                ],
              )),
        ));
  }

  InputDecoration _buildInputDecoration(String label, IconData suffixIcon) {
    return InputDecoration(
        fillColor: Color(0xAA494A59),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0x35949494))
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)
        ),
        filled: true,
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF949494)),
        labelText: label,
        suffixIcon: Icon(suffixIcon, color: Color(0xFF949494)),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0))
    );
  }

}
```

And here is the snippet of the error:
E/flutter ( 9982): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter ( 9982): #0      _LoginViewState._submitForm (package:project/screens/login_screen.dart:27:30)
E/flutter ( 9982): #1      _LoginViewState.build. (package:project/screens/login_screen.dart:112:57)
E/flutter ( 9982): #2      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1183:21)
E/flutter ( 9982): #3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:275:24)
E/flutter ( 9982): #4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:652:11)
E/flutter ( 9982): #5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:309:5)
E/flutter ( 9982): #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:7)
E/flutter ( 9982): #7      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:630:9)
E/flutter ( 9982): #8      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98:12)
E/flutter ( 9982): #9      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes. (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:143:9)
E/flutter ( 9982): #10     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:633:13)
E/flutter ( 9982): #11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:141:18)
E/flutter ( 9982): #12     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:127:7)
E/flutter ( 9982): #13     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:488:19)
E/flutter ( 9982): #14     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:468:22)
E/flutter ( 9982): #15     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:439:11)
E/flutter ( 9982): #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:413:7)
E/flutter ( 9982): #17     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:376:5)
E/flutter ( 9982): #18     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:323:7)
E/flutter ( 9982): #19     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:292:9)
E/flutter ( 9982): #20     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:328:13)
E/flutter ( 9982): #21     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:410:7)
E/flutter ( 9982): #22     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:262:31)
E/flutter ( 9982):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form key is missing from the form widget.

```
Form(
  key: _formKey,
...
)
```